# How add new field into reducer using Immer.js?

Tags: javascript, redux, reducers, immer.js, optional-chaining

For example,

```
state = {
  data: {}
}
```

How can I add a new nested field into an object?
I cannot set that field, because have an error `Cannot read property 'date' of undefined`

```
const reducer = produce((draft, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case 'ACTION_SUCCESS':
      draft.data.children.date = action.response;
   }
});
```

As a result I want:

```
  data: {
     children: {
        data: 'date'
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normal JS object manipulation rules apply here. You can't write `obj.x.y.z =` if there is no `.y` field yet - you have to create that first.

Comment: What is the best way to create a new field in an object?

Comment: Like I said, it's just normal JS from your code's perspective. So, something like `someObj.newField = 123`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried lodash/set?

```js
import set from "lodash/set"

const obj= set({}, "path.to.nested.field", value)
```